# Eruv and underground transportation

Tags: halacha, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, eruv-chatzerot, orach-chaim, demography

According to Halacha, a kosher eruv that allows one to carry on Shabbat can only be constructed in an area that is not a Biblical Reshut Harabim, which according to some views is 600,000 people. My question is, for the purpose of Hilchos Eruvin, are people traversing in underground transportation counted with the people above ground as part of the population to make a Reshut Harabim? For example, people in an underground subway?

Comment: Similarly counting people on both the first floor and the second floor of a house.